# Java null check

Tags: java, concurrency, null

I have one `thread1`:

```
if(object != null){
   object.play();
}
```

and another `thread2` that can write `null` into `object` reference at any time.

I will run these threads at same time. I know `thread2` can rewrite `object` reference after the `null` check and that will throw `NullPointerException`. Is it possible for `thread2` to rewrite `object` reference after `NullPointerException` check?

Comment: Perhaps use a `boolean` flag to indicate to the other thread that it's null?

Comment: You mean, between dereferencing `object` and calling `play()`? Absolutely. The rule of thumb is that without proper barriers and synchronisation, absolutely anything can happen. That's obviously not literally true but it often helps if you approach it that way.

Comment: What's the difference between "null check" and "NullPointerException check" ?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to read up on the `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: How is the `object` reference shared between threads? Is it a static variable in your `Runnable` class? or is it passed to each thread as an argument?

Comment: @Redandwhite I dare you to put that as an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to for thread2 to rewrite object reference after NullPointerException check ?

Absolutely - it could change the value of `object` while the `play()` method is executing, if that's what you mean. That wouldn't cause an error in itself.

Note that without synchronization or other memory barriers, thread2 could change the value of `object` without thread1 noticing for an indeterminate period of time.

It's hard to say what you ought to do, without any other knowledge of the bigger aim of the code.

Comment: Well, I dind't have anything specific when I wrote it, It was just a thought. What do you mean by 'That wouldn't cause an error in itself.' ? I would not cause NullPointerException or any error ? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @jellyfication: It won't cause a `NullPointerException` *after* the initial check. The value of `object` is evaluated, and that determines whether a `NullPointerException` is thrown, and the target of the call. Changes to `object` won't affect which target is used.

Answer (score 5):

Simple `synchronized` example:

```
/**
To maintain thread safety, only access this through getter and setter
or other synchronized method
**/
private ObjectType object;

public synchronized void setObject(ObjectType object) {
  this.object = object;
}

public synchronized ObjectType getObject() {
  return object;
}

public void doPlay() {
  final ObjectType obj = getObject();
  //here, thread 2 can change "object", but it's not going to affect this thread
  //as we already safely got our reference to "object" in "obj".
  if(obj != null){ 
   obj.play(); 
  }
}

public synchronized void alterativeDoPlay() {
  //the difference here is that another thread won't be able to change "object"
  //until the object's play() method has completed.
  //depending on the code in play, this has potential for deadlocks, where as
  //the other `doPlay` has zero deadlock potential.
  if(object != null){
   object.play(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) here. Where Thread1 will wait to count down by Thread2 and you can perform the task in thread2 and stop count down.

Code snippet -

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
new Thread1(latch).start();
new Thread2(latch).start();
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
  private final CountDownLatch startLatch;

  public Thread1(CountDownLatch startLatch) {
    this.startLatch = startLatch;
  }
  public void run() {
    try {
      startLatch.await();
      // ... perform task
    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
  }
}

public class Thread1 extends Thread {
  private final CountDownLatch stopLatch;

  public Thread1(CountDownLatch stopLatch) {
    this.stopLatch = stopLatch;
  }
  public void run() {
    try {
      // perform task
    } finally {
      stopLatch.countDown();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `object` is an instance variable or a static variable that can be changed from multiple threads, its value can change between the time you test it in the `if` statement and the time when you call its instance method.

You can modify the code to avoid this problem by copying the object into a local variable, like this:

```
Playable objectCopy = object;
if(objectCopy != null) {
    objectCopy.play();
}
```

Since `objectCopy` is a local variable, its value cannot change between the test and the call of `play`. Of course the state of the playable object itself can change, but that is not something that can be fixed by `null` checking.

Comment: This does not alone make it threadsafe. `object` would need to be marked as `volatile`

Comment: Don't disagree will solve NPE, but is my understanding that without `volatile` (or other synchronization preferrable) thread 1 could be looking at cached value for object, so changes made by thread 2 may not be seen. So that's not going to be result OP is looking for/expecting.

Comment: @weston Absolutely! Without synchronization, this exercise will be full of unexpected results (unexpected in a bad way, of course).

Comment: `Playable objectCopy = object;` does not create a new object...now you just have another reference to the same object, and have achieved nothing.

Comment: @lynks Of course I achieved *something*! My newly created reference to the same object is *local*, and is therefore immune to possible changes of the original reference. This makes my code fragment free of possible null pointer exceptions - quite a departure from the OP's code!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are correct i guess. i did not mean my comment to sound short. you can be certain that your reference is not a reference  to null, but to what exactly is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

According to **Brian's Law** :

`When we write a variable, which next has to be read by another thread, or when we are reading a variable which has lately been written by another thread, then use synchronization.
 Synchronize the atomic statements or getter/setters which has access to the crucial state of data with the same monitor lock.`

**-** Use `synchronization`.

**-** You can use `CountDownLatch` from `java.util.concurrent`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some form of synchronisation primitive to solve this problem. See "Syncrhonised Statements" [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html). In your case you will need to wrap the whole `if` block and any places in any threads that use or update `object2`.

Answer (score 0):

As my professor said: "Concurrency is a pretty unstable guy. We never know what to expect of him." Comming to your question:

> Is it possible for thread2 to rewrite object reference after
>   NullPointerException check?

Yes

Thread2 can access the object many times during 1 occurrence of thread1. Or the other way around. There may be many occurrences of thread1, while thread2 accesses the object.

If you use simple

> System.out.println();

in many places in your code, you may notice the output in the console to be displayed AFTER the NullPointerException error(if it wasn't caught).

Comment: *"Concurrency is a pretty unstable guy. We never know what to excpect of him."* - That is true in the general sense.  But the flip side is that if you pay attention to the details, you can write concurrent code that is 100% reliable and predictable.

Comment: @StephenC Later on the guy introduced his wife Synchronization ;)