# Can the below program crash?

Tags: java

For example, there is a piece of Java code, Home is a Java class, mHome can be a member in any object:

```
if((mHome != null) && (mHome.mName == "xxx"))  
{      ......      }
```

My question is here. Is that possible that Home ref is null when running the condition `Home.mName == "xxx"`. For example, after running the statement `Home != null`, the thread is switch out, and another thread put Home to be null.

Comment: Is Home local to this program or shared between multiple threads?

Comment: Every code can crash. Now, do you know why Home.mName == "xxx" is bad coding? there are two reasons for that. (or three, depending on what mName is)

Comment: Java is pass by value. If threads share a reference to `Home` and one of the threads set the reference to home as null, chances are that other threads will not really get impacted. But again, this is only one possible scenario.

Comment: sorry, I correct my original post. For example, mHome can be accessed in different threads.

Comment: It is very important for you to mention whether `mHome` is an instance variable in your class or a local variable in the method

Comment: Well, you use reference equality instead of .equals() to test the equality of a string, so this will not work

Comment: not to mention the fact that the { ... } part can crash as well.
Having bad code is not the only thing that can cause a crash: if your resources are completely used and you then call that if statement, yup, 'll crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the amount of code that you have given, it is hard to say whether this piece will fail or not. For example,

```
public test(){
    Home home = ...//call the constructor of home to create an instance
    if(null!=home && home.mName=="xxx") {// bad comparison of string and bad way to access an instance variable
        //some code
    }
}
```

in the above case the comparison `home.mName=="xxx"`will not fail(result in null that is), as `home` is local to the method.
But

```
public test() {
    // assuming home is an instance variable
    if(null!=this.getHome() && this.getHome().mName=="xxx") {// bad comparison of string and bad way to access an instance variable
        //some code
    }
}
```

}

chances are there when

- -> a thread `A` has completed executing `null!=home`
- -> `A` is put to **sleep**
- -> Another thread `B` changes the value of the variable `home` to `null`
- -> Thread `B` is put to **sleep**
- -> `A` **resumes execution**
- -> **NullPointerException**

if the latter was the case then, you should make sure that the method accessing the value of the variable `home` is `synchronized`(thread safe basically). But it is a little tricky to understand synchronization. For example,

```
public class WrongThreadSafety {
  private static String s;
  public synchronized String setString(String s) {
    this.s = s;
  }

  public synchronized String getStringLength() {
    return s.length();
  }

}
```

Though the above class has methods that are `synchronized`, it is really not thread safe. the method `setString` and `getStringLength` are thread-safe individually. That is two threads cannot access the method `setString` or `getStringLength` at the same time, but nothing is stopping a thread from calling the `setString` method with a null, and at the same time another thread calling the `getStringLength` method.

Comment: HI Black Panther, 
Thanks a lot for your kind answers! I totally understand what you are saying. A

Comment: HI Black Panther, 
Thanks a lot for your kind answers! I totally understand what you are saying. And I think now there is no tech questions.
But I am still a little puzzled. I think, when we doing program, such case is very common. But we seldom do the protection as you said and usually have no problem.
So....I don't know. Can't explain the strange issue I really met in our company's real project.

Comment: You are welcome.. :) If you are doing this in a non-threading program (Again, it is a little tricky to explain this, as every program has threads int it), it won't pose an issue. As mostly the object will be created locally, lets say per request if its a j2EE app. So it won't be a problem. But if it is a shared resource, then it would be. For instance, same user logged into the application via 2 different browsers at the same time, and adding a product in browser `A` and removing it from browser `B`, if you are not handling it properly, it would be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

> DISCLAIMER: I don't code java, but the question is more of a general multithreading question and so the answer should apply to java as well.

As you clearly understand, a different thread with access to `Home` can change anything, and if a context switch happens "between" the 2 parts of the `if` statement and it will fail.

There is a way to protect your code from this risk WITHOUT applying locking / synchronization methods and that is by grabbing a local reference (using a private variable) before the `if` statement and then you know for sure that if the variable isn't null, it's safe to access it's members. (*Note: This is only true in a garbage collecting environment, in C++ for example you might end up holding a reference to a deleted object and that will crash too).

Comment: Remember that java is pass by value.

Comment: HI Amit, if I change code to mHome.mName = (mHome == null)? 1: 2, can crash happen?

Comment: user3236879 : has it ever occurred that the rest of the code can also have an impact on whether or not it can crash?

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is ==> yes it is possible.

You need to make your code threadsafe  . For that use synchronization

Here is a sample code employing synchronization from the link http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=124425

```
package com.jgk.patterns.singleton;

public class JGKSingleton {

  /* Here is the instance of the Singleton */
  private static JGKSingleton instance_;

  /* Need the following object to synchronize */
  /* a block */
  private static Object syncObject_;

  /* Prevent direct access to the constructor
  private JGKSingleton() {
    super();
  }


  public static JGKSingleton getInstance() {

    /* in a non-thread-safe version of a Singleton   */
    /* the following line could be executed, and the */ 
    /* thread could be immediately swapped out */
    if (instance_ == null) {

      synchronized(syncObject_) {

        if (instance_ == null) {
           instance_ = new JGKSingleton();
        }

      }

    }
    return instance_;
  }
}
```

This below link from stackoverflow shows how this issue is tackled in different ways.

[Java null check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781828/java-null-check)

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: `mHome` has a local scope i.e. `mHome` is method argument or `mHome` is defined inside the method

No, variable will not be visible to other threads hence can not have two different values in the provided statement

Case 2: `mHome` is an instance variable, If `mHome` is an instance variable and you have scenarios where the given statement can be executed by multiple Threads, then there is a possibility that the two statements i.e. the `null` check and equality check can see different values. In such case you need to use `synchronized` keyword to create a critical section where only one thread can enter at a time